# Notifications for a specific time in java

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I am making an app that requires push notfications. I have got the push notifications working and can set a time for the notifications to happen. The only thing is I have to lik in radio buttons so when rabiobutton1 is selected the notification is in 1 minute, radiobutto2 is 10 minutes etc.
Below is my code for the notifications:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Settings.this, Start.class);
    startActivity(i);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // 10 minutes * 60000 milliseconds(1 minute)
                Thread.sleep(60000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Intent intent = new Intent();
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Settings.this, 0, intent, 0);
            Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(Settings.this)
                    .setTicker("TickerTitle")
                    .setContentTitle("Price-Watch")
                    .setContentText("Check Your Items Price")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.pw)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
                    noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    nm.notify(0, noti);
                }
            }).start();
```

Does anyone know how I would do this? I have looked around and couldnt find anything that would help me. Im new to java and android studios so thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if understood alright, but i hope help you.

You can try some like this.

1) Get your radioGroup and set a listener.

```
RadioGroup radioTimeGroup = (radioTimeGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioTimeGroup);

final long selectedTime = 0l;

radioTimeGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        switch(checkedId) {
            case R.id.rdbOpcion1:
                selectedTime = 60000;//1 minute
                break;
            case R.id.rdbOpcion2:
                selectedTime = 60000 * 10;//10 minute
                break;

            default:
                //Your default action.
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

2) Set your selected time

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(selectedTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Settings.this, 0, intent, 0);
            Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(Settings.this)
                    .setTicker("TickerTitle")
                    .setContentTitle("Price-Watch")
                    .setContentText("Check Your Items Price")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.pw)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
                    noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    nm.notify(0, noti);
                }
            }).start();
```

In this case you also can use a Handler and specific it a postDelay

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Settings.this, 0, intent, 0);
                Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(Settings.this)
                        .setTicker("TickerTitle")
                        .setContentTitle("Price-Watch")
                        .setContentText("Check Your Items Price")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.pw)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
                noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.notify(0, noti);
            }
        }, selectedTime);
```

With the last method your code is executed after "selectedTime".

PD: Sorry for my low english level. I hope help you.

Comment: careful about creating a Handler anonymous class, as this could be a memory leak.  Try making it a static class.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Kristy Welsh.